# ObjectBox for dart: cannot compile on iOS

Tags: compiler-errors, objectbox

It seems I cannot compile ObjectBox for Dart on iOS (currently using a MacBook Pro with m1 chip). As specified in Readme, I increased the deployment target to iOS 11, and replaced ARCHS_STANDARD with ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT. Update pod as well:

pod install
pod update
I attach below screenshots from android studio / Xcode, along with compiler error.

Anybody knows how I can fix that?

Android studio) https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTq9G.png Xcode build) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqfv4.jpg Xcode setup) https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEvTH.png Xcode setup) https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq9TG.png Xcode compiler error https://i.stack.imgur.com/sosvL.jpg

Comment: It would help if you could share for example the entity class code so one can reproduce your issue. Also it generally is a good idea to share text and not pictures. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to paste texts but stackoverflow editor conflated it with code and asked for formatting it properly. Used pics as a quick workaround. No class code attached because it is objectbox’s official example app.

Answer (score 0):

The missing file is generated by running `flutter pub run build_runner build` - that should help.